# Setting the value of a lookupfield(sharepoint dropdown formfield) in sharepoint 2010 list forms

Tags: sharepoint-designer, jquery, lookup-column, list-form, dropdown

How can i set the value of sharepoint form field dropdown box(lookupfield) in sharepoint list form when the form gets saved (using jquery)
note: the lookupfield (dropdown formfield renders as input if it contains values more than 20)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just implemented such a solution a couple of weeks ago

Here is a [very good post](http://geekswithblogs.net/SoYouKnow/archive/2011/04/06/setting-sharepoint-drop-down-lists-w-jquery---20-items.aspx) that will explain all.

Answer (score 0):

So I have a field called "Data Classification":

```
var dataClsField = $('select[title="Data Classification"]');
```

I was trying to set this field with the value of another dropdown called "DataClass" that I got using this code:

```
var clsFieldValue = $('select[id*="DataClass"] option:selected').val();
```

For some crazy reason, I had to do both of these options to get my first field to set right:

```
dataClsField.find('option[value="'+clsFieldValue+'"]').prop('selected', true);
dataClsField.val(clsFieldValue.val());
```

Note: This was with 2 dropdowns with less than 20 items in each.  I believe the only difference, jQuery-wise, when it goes over that, is that "select" becomes "input" on your selector.